# Circuitikz, draw a component within a node

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-node

using circuitikz (siunitx),
I would like to draw a diode within a rectangle, but the option to place text within a node doesn't allow that:

```
\draw (0,0) to node[draw,rectangle, fill=white] {a diode instead of text} (4,0);
```

How would I do that?

How would I add a text next to the node, how do I control on which side the text is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\draw (0,0) to[D] node[draw,left,text width=4cm, text height=1cm,inner sep=0]{}  (4,0);
```

[image]

You can add text with another node.

Comment: Mush easier than using a savebox.